# Average time between Transactions (SSAS)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have built a calculated member on an SSAS multidimensional cube in order to calculate the average time in days between transactions of members. The code I use is fairly simple :

```
[Measures].[Distinct Days]/[Measures].LoyalTransactions
```

The Distinct Days measure is calculated from :

```
DISTINCTCOUNT(DistinctDays)
```

Where DistinctDays is a dynamic set with the following expression :

```
{[Measures].[Loyalty Fact Count]}
*
DISTINCT({ [TimeDim Transactions].[DateKey].[DateKey]})
```

The problem is that it has very poor performance probably due to the distinct count of the days. The results also are somewhat unstable, for example the results are not the same when I filter the transaction dates from the month attribute and when I filter using the date attribute (date>=FirstDayOfMonth and date<=LastDayOfMonth)

Is there a way to calculate this measure differently?

Comment: How do you do this? `(date>=FirstDayOfMonth and date<=LastDayOfMonth)` using a third party tool or via `mdx`?

Comment: I use date filters on Power view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to test but trying to adapt from this Mosha article (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2008/06/14/counting-distinct-values-in-mdx.aspx).
Does it execute?

```
Sum([DistinctDays] AS x,
   1/Filter([DistinctDays], 
   x.Current is x.CurrentMember
   ).Count)
```

Comment: It executes, but the result is wrong. I will try to modify it